# Recursively parsing JSON response using GSON

Tags: java, optimization, json, gson

I have a URL which I am executing it and it is returning the below string as a JSON response. I am using GSON to parse JSON.

In the below JSON, `"resourceId"` contains an IP address.

```
{
   "status":{
      "code":"200",
      "msg":"ok",
   },
   "hasmore":true,
   "count":1000,
   "result":[
      {
         "_type":"Calculate",
         "resourceId":"1.2.3.4",
         "_oid":"522b216"
      },
      {
         "_type":"Calculate",
         "resourceId":"5.6.7.8",
         "_oid":"53cea4ad1"
      },
      {
         "_type":"Calculate",
         "resourceId":"9.10.11.12",
         "_oid":"51f98cce1c12c6"
      }
   ],
   "pagination":{
      "cursor":[
         "",
         "545b3bba43a2",
         ""
      ],
      "limit":[
         10000,
         1000,
         1000
      ],
      "skipEmptyPage":false
   },
   "next":{
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"/urlB"
   }
}
```

Now from the above JSON response, I need to extract all the `resourceId` values and populate it into a `List<String>`.

In my above JSON string, there is a property called `"hasmore"` and in all the JSON response this field will be there always so if `"hasmore"` is true, then it means there are more IP Address which will be there in another URL and that URL is present in `"next"` JSON object in the same JSON response at the bottom so I need to execute that URL and get the JSON response back and that response will be similar to what I have above so populate the IP address into the same list and keep on doing this until you see `"hasmore"` is false.

In general, I will have original `URLA` which I will execute it and get the JSON response back which will look like as shown above, parse that JSON populate all the `resourceId` into a List and then check if `"hasmore"` is true, then it means there will be another URL at the bottom which is `URLB` so now execute this URL again, get the JSON response back which will be similar to what I have above and then keep on populating `resourceId` into the same list
and again check if `"hasmore"` is true or not. Keep on doing this until you see `"hasmore"` is false.

In short, `ips` list should have all the IP Address in it since JSON response is coming back as paginated.

I have got the below code working fine:

```
public static List<String> getListOfIps(String alias) {
    List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();
    String url = null;
    boolean hasMore = true;
    try {
        // original url
        url = getURL(alias);
        while (hasMore) {
            String response = getJsonResponse(url);

            // parse response
            if (response != null) {
                JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(response);
                JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();

                hasMore = jobject.get("hasmore").getAsBoolean();

                JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("result");
                if (hasMore) {
                    url = "http://machine.vip.domain.com/ppt" + jobject.getAsJsonObject("next").get("url").getAsString();
                }

                for (JsonElement type : jarray) {
                    ips.add(type.getAsJsonObject().get("resourceId").getAsString());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log an exception using logger
    }
    return ips;
}
```

I am opting for code review for this method to see whether there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: Any chance you could be sent into an infinite loop? `urlA` -> `urlB` -> `urlA` for example?

Comment: @mjolka No that will not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the following POJOs

```
class Result {
    private String resourceId;
}

class Next{
    private String url;
}

class Response{
    private boolean hasMore;
    private List<Result> result;
    private Next next;
}
// If other fields are required add them.
// Have their getters/setters.
// Have the hashCode,equals,toString
```

Your `getListOfIps()` could look like this:

```
List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();
Response response = null;
String url = getURL(alias);
do{
    String responseJson = getJsonResponse(url);
    try{
        response = new Gson().fromJson(responseJson , Response.Class);
    } catch( // Json Exceptions thrown by this function){
        // Log the exception and handle it .
    }
    // Check if response and response.result is non null
    // Loop through and extract the non-null resourceId
    // update url
    if(response.hasMore && (response.next!=null) && (response.next.url.length()>0)){
        url= response.next.url;
    }else{
        url = null;
    }
  } while(url);
```

The code is more of a "steps to follow". Hope it helps. 
Try the code and you can post the updated code if its better. 
For Gson help follow this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is there any reason of using url in the while loop for check? Can we not use hasMore boolean to do that?

Comment: it may so happen that hasMore is true but url may be null or empty. So just a safe check. You can choose otherwise.